# Universe Colors

Tags: fringe

Fringe used to indicate the universe an episode would mostly play in by adapting the title sequence. This way, the different universes were matched with a color, which also makes referring to them in discussion easier.

Not counting the retro-credits for the episodes that played in the past, nor the Observer-infested future of the orange-verse, there are:

- blue-verse: our side, seasons 1 - 3
- red-verse: other side, seasons 1 - 3
- gray-verse: ex-blue-verse that destroyed the red-verse, as seen in "The Day We Died"
- orange-verse: like blue-verse, but Peter died in Reiden Lake, season 4

**Was there, however, any color assigned to the other side of season 4 (that would reappear for a few scenes in the finale)?** It is *not* the red-verse, as there are various differences; for example, Broyles died in the red-verse, whereas he is still alive in the other side during season 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a color was never assigned. The Yellowverse encompassed both sides.

Comment: This is a very short answer. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @JamesSheridan Normally I'd agree with you, but in this case, isn't this answer all there is to it? :) "No, no other color was assigned"?

Comment: I don't know, not being a *Fringe* fan. I simply find any answer that isn't even two lines long to be far too short to be conclusive. It's not just a simple yes-no question.

Comment: That would make terminology much more confusing (as in season 4, the universes were linked, but by no means merged - e.g. there still were two Olivias), but I agree it's reasonable to assume the producers didn't think far enough about the coloration thing to make it consistently usable as a universe designation. I can only accept one answer, so I will accept this one and upvote the other one.

Comment: @JamesSheridan it kinda is a yes-no question: "Q: Did the opening credits of Fringe have a different color in Season 4 for episodes set primarily in the other universe?" A: "No."

Comment: I still think it requires elaboration, but the QA obviously found it to be good enough, so I'll go with their judgement.

Answer (score 2):

I thought the amber colour was used to represent how both universes were joined together, as it contains elements of both blue and red colouring.
It's clearly said by Peter in a season 4 episode that he has returned to the universe he grew up in (my paraphrasing), but as an alternate timeline due to his deletion from history, as he "died" at Reiden Lake. In that same way, the other universe they experience in season 4 is just the regular red universe but also with an altered timeline.

Comment: That would make terminology much more confusing (as in season 4, the universes were linked, but by no means merged - e.g. there still were two Olivias), but I agree it's reasonable to assume the producers didn't think far enough about the coloration thing to make it consistently usable as a universe designation. I can only accept one answer, so I will accept the other one and upvote this one.